# What is the .NET Equivalent of Java's LockSupport.parknanos?

Tags: java, .net, multithreading

Essentially I need a way to initiate sub-microsecond thread sleeps as [parknanos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkNanos%28java.lang.Object,%20long%29) does.

Thread.Sleep seems accurate only to the millisecond.

Comment: Could you tell us you need to wait for less than 1 µs?

Comment: @Simon Svensson: maybe the OP needs to do that for one of the same reasons that method like *parkNanos* do, well... exist!?   ; )

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` isn't even accurate to the millisecond by default. 16ms is typical, unless somebody called `TimeBeginPeriod` to shorten it. This is a windows limitation, not a .net one. I'd be surprised if java managed to sleep with such accuracy. Busy waits on the other hand, can have higher accuracy.

Comment: Interesting lecture on this subject(accuracy of system clocks under different OS, from java-concurrency developer David Holmes): http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks

Comment: Essentially we're porting some code from Java and are thus trying to maintain equivalence between the two code bases. We already have a wait strategy based on Thread.SpinWait. This one uses parknanos and we're trying to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Thread.SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx)

Comment: "The duration of the wait therefore depends on the speed of the processor." - not very predictable...

Comment: maybe - but it will allow you to wait smaller intervals. Thread.Sleep only gives you a 100ms or so accuracy anyway. Plus you can use Diagnostics.StopWatch to measure how much time you've been waiting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: The main disadvantage of this is that it's a busy wait. But with the OP's requirements this a necessary evil.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - right- but I don't think you can do better than that in .Net.

Comment: You're right CodeInChaos. I'm trying to avoid a busy wait if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the performance timers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650674.aspx

However the use of interop may limit this approach

Comment: I think the `StopWatch` class is based on `QueryPerformanceCounter`, so you don't need any manual interop.

Comment: @CodeInChaos you are right - my knoweldge is old, I kept thinking there must be a class in the framework but couldn't find anything but what I had done in old .net2 days - add it as an answer.